# Connecting to windows network drive from macos via python

Tags: python, macos

I want to access new drive of windows ex. `10.11.123.145` with username `chaitanya` and password `123@abc` via python to copy some content from new drive to my macos desktop.
How can I do this?

`mount_smbfs "//chaitanya:123@abc@10.11.123.145/folder_name"` is not working.
It gives nothing output.

I tried doing "open //chaitanya:123@abc@server/10.10.93.167" but then it is trying to open //167 and giving error.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does the command you show work in Terminal? I would recommend showing how you are attempting to use it within Python.

Comment: I am initially trying to do it in cmd. It is not working in cmd as well. After it works on cmd I will use os.system(command) in python.

Comment: So to clarify, you are attempting the command on Windows?

Comment: No, I am trying on mac os. When I try "open//chaitanya:123@abc@server/10.10.93.167" or "open //chaitanya:123@abc@10.10.93.167", it is giving this error that it is trying to connect smb://167 and please check IP address.

Comment: How did you call them from Python? Can you post related code?

Comment: I haven't call it via python. I will figure it out once I can access nw drive via cmd.

Comment: By the way, there is no `CMD` on a Mac, you likely mean **Terminal**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `@` in your password is where things go wrong, so you'll probably want to encode it.

```
mount_smbfs //chaitanya:123%40abc@10.11.123.145/folder_name /existing_dir
```

Using `%40` instead of `@` in your password should let the command know where the real `@` is.

You could probably also do:

```
mount_smbfs //chaitanya:123\@abc@10.11.123.145/folder_name /existing_dir
```

Which escapes the `@` in your password.

Comment: Thanks for solution. But it is giving error 'no route to host' whereas i can connect to server via "Connect to server" option.

Comment: @Chaitanya: Is the Windows machine part of a domain or workgroup?

Comment: Yes. ch.lan is domain name. I tried using it as //ch.lan;.. but still getting same error.

Comment: @Chaitanya: Try doing `mount_smbfs //'ch.lan;chaitanya:123\@abc'@10.11.123.145/folder_name /existing_dir` - you might not need to escape the `@` in this case because of the quotes around the `domain;username:password`.

Comment: I tried this but I am getting the error "Server connection failed: Unknown error -1". I don't know if this will help but I am trying to access from mac vm.